# Cannot resolve method .into

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

i use glide method.

```
Glide.with(this._activity).load((String) this._filePaths.get(position)).
                apply(new RequestOptions().
                        override(dimen, dimen).
                        centerCrop().
                        diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).
                        into(imageView);
```

i get error Cannot resolve method 'into(android.widget.ImageView)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing one ")" after the `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)`:

```
Glide.with(this._activity).load((String) this._filePaths.get(position)).
            apply(new RequestOptions().
                    override(dimen, dimen).
                    centerCrop().
                    diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)).
                    into(imageView);
```